# Unexpected result in validation rule

Tags: validation-rule, isblank, empty

I have a validation rules as follows:

```
a <> related__r.b
```

When a is null/or empty, the validation rule fails to trigger regardless of the value in b.

I fixed the logic with the following:

```
OR(a <> related__r.b, AND( ISBLANK(a), NOT(ISBLANK(related__r.b), AND( ISBLANK(related__r.b), NOT(ISBLANK(a) )
```

Any ideas what is happening? Is this feature, a bug or a known issue?

Thank you

[UPDATE]

a and b are both percentage input fields. b is in another object linked through lookup field. I've updated the code snippet to show a relationship. In my testing related__c is not null/empty.

Comment: Without knowing what `a` and `b` were, I'm not sure what we'd tell you. Were relationships involved? Different data types? We need a bit of specifics here. In the most general case `a <> b` work as expected, but there may be some edge cases.

Comment: a and b are both percentage input fields.

Answer (score 0):

I know percentage fields are a little goofy, but, given the description here...

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ZvAvAAK

...I'd expect the validation rule to return false (no error) when either field is blank; not just when field A is blank.  Is that what you're seeing?